# Jump timer in unity 3d and how to define spacebar in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I was wondering if anybody knew how to set up a jump limit or jump timer so that users cant spam jump on unity. this is my first time using C# and I'm not sure how to use it properly yet here is my code

Also, if anybody knows how to define the spacebar instead of using the w key that would be great.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float ForwardForce = 800f;
    public float SideWaysForce = 300f;
    public float JumpForce = 200f;
    public LayerMask GroundLayers;
    public BoxCollider col;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //change forward force 
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, ForwardForce * Time.deltaTime);


        if ( Input.GetKey("d") )
        {
            rb.AddForce(SideWaysForce, 0, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-SideWaysForce, 0, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, JumpForce, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacebar input: Input.GetKey("space")

Create a bool and track if user is jumping based on if the height is more than the original height. Of course you can change/customize/optimize this so suit the needs of your game

```
bool isJumping;
float originalPositionY;

void Start() {
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();    
originalPositionY = rb.position.y;

../

if (rb.position.y > originalPositionY) {
isJumping = true;
} else {
isJumping = false;

if (Input.GetKey("space") && !isJumping)
{
    rb.AddForce(0, JumpForce, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
}

../
```